# Is it possible to use fetchUrl(·), but to get the result after html loads?

Tags: javascript, html, fetch-api, urlfetch, domcontentloaded

Suppose a webpage with, say, url `'http://example.com'` has html & javascript:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(event) {
  document.getElementById('ergebnis').textContent='2'; // haha, I tricked you , fetch!
});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <div>The answer is <span id='ergebnis'>42</span>.</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Suppose I call elsewhere `var x = UrlFetchApp.fetch('http://example.com').getContentText();`. Then one gets `x = 42`. Had Fetch however properly waited for the code to load, one should obtain `x = 2`.

Is it possible to tell fetch to wait until the HTML fully loads (*eg* until `'DOMContentLoaded'` holds), before it runs `getContentText`?

Comment: You seem to be confusing front end and back end api's. Really not clear what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: I explained it fully in my OP: I need to upon input of a list of URLs use URLFetching to fetch the html that loads. Using `UrlFetchApp.fetch(…)` works… with the catch, that it loads the source code and not the finalised rendering of the HTML. My example tries to demonstrate this. If you were to use `UrlFetchApp.fetch(…)` on a website with the above code, then you would get 42 instead of 2, which is undesirable. Obviously I’m working with more complicated issues than this. The example is supposed to be simple.

Comment: oh...so you are trying to scrape another site (again..objective is not clear)? If so need to use a headless browser to scrape it when content is loaded using asynchronous javascript

Comment: are you sure you're not looking to go headless?

Comment: try to go for phantomjs or selenium

Comment: Scrape another site? I don’t know what that means. I need to read some attributes off some client’s sites and perform some operations on these attributes. It is crucial that I read off the attributes that *actually* get loaded, and not merely those that merely stand in the source code, which is what fetch is currently delivering. What does *going headless* mean? I’ll look into phantomjs & selenium.

Comment: With Phantomjs I guess you mean something like this:`var page = require('webpage').create();
var url = 'http://phantomjs.org/';
page.open(url, function (status) {
  //Page is loaded! Do something!
  phantom.exit();
});`